# List index out of range and I can't figure out why?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I've been trying to solve problems on code wars and for this problem my code returns an

> "IndexError: list index out of range" in Line 13.

Can someone explain why?

> You will be given an array of numbers. You have to sort the odd
> numbers in ascending order while leaving the even numbers at their
> original positions.

```
[7, 1]  =>  [1, 7], 
[5, 8, 6, 3, 4]  =>  [3, 8, 6, 5, 4] ,
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]  =>  [1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0]
```

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    dup_arr = []

    for i in range(len(source_array)-1):
        if source_array[i]%2 != 0:
            dup_arr.append(source_array[i])

    dup_arr = sorted(dup_arr)
    j = 0
    l = 0
    for j in range(len(source_array)):
        if source_array[j] %2 != 0:
            source_array[j] = dup_arr[l]
            l += 1
    
    return source_array
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(source_array)-1)` Why `-1` here?

Comment: Why ? Because you increase `l` without checking the value, so at a time you're out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have debug your program and `print(">>", dup_arr)` you'll see that you were missing the last odd numbers, because of your wrong range, it should be `range(len(source_array))`

```
for i in range(len(source_array)):
    if source_array[i] % 2 != 0:
        dup_arr.append(source_array[i])
```

Know that you can iterate on values directly, that makes syntax nicer when indice isn't needed

```
for val in source_array:
    if val % 2 != 0:
        dup_arr.append(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

On first glance - check if the size of `dup_array` is what you want. In particular, check whether `for i in range(len(source_array)-1):` iterates over all values you want. Maybe there's an off-by-one error in that line?